# Macbook pro retina doesn't recognize WiFi network

Tags: mac, wireless-networking

I'm new to mac world and already having some issues.

My MacBook Pro with retina display does not automatically discovers my WiFi network. Other devices (like iPad I'm using now or Windows laptops) find the network automatically and allow connection with no problem.

The Mac on the other hand does not display network on WiFi network list, nor does it find the network when trying to manually enter SSID to other networks.

I'm pretty sure that the Mac network adapter works correctly since it discoveres other WiFi networks and was connecting correctly to other networks, just that one gives me some troubles.

Of course I tried restarting both the Mac and router, to no avail.

Fun part is *the same router model works fine with my Mac in different appartment*.

My network configuration is pretty basic: automatically broadcasting network, WPA2 personal encryption. Network is in G standard.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Is there a switch on the keyboard or on the side of the computer to enable/disable wifi? If not, is there an option to do that in the operating system itself?

Comment: @ionFish - That is no hardware switch for wireless on the case for sure (Apple is aesthetically focused, not practicality focused) nor on the keyboard.  Regardless, since they are able to connect elsewhere (seemingly with no change), that is definitely not the issue.  Not too sure what else would be causing this, does your wireless network have weird symbols in it? (.,/,@,#,etc?)  Can you try WEP on your router just to see if it's an issue with the Mac's WPA_supplicant?  Otherwise, hardwire to your router and do all the updates possible to start.

Comment: I didn't notice any switch, but there is option in system, tried turning it off and on again, but it made no difference. And like i said, other networks are discovered so wifi seems to work correctly on computer,but there might be some System settings i'm not aware off that may cause such issues.

Comment: Tried removing all security from network, still do not work. Only wierd symbol is underscore "_" but I don't think this counts as weird. Hardwiring to router is also not an option - mac does not have ethernet port, cheers Apple!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is how I solved it:

1. Connect to your modem with a cable
2. Ensure the wireless is enabled by logging in to the modem settings
3. I just changed the network name (and it worked!) for me.

Comment: Well, tried that, but to no avail. Like noted in comments to question, my mac does not have ethernet cable connection, but I changed name (and basically all other possibile settings) of my network and it still did not get recognized by Mac. On all other networks it still works fine, so it's just one network that gives me some trouble. Not like this is big deal, I don't use it normally anyway, but still...